# MySQL Cannot create view for subquery in from clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1349

I'm trying to make query that will display top 10 Systems and the 'Other' as 11th row. I made union query. I found that the query I build returns the 'Other' record for each System name that is not in Top10, so I made select in select to sum all 'Other's. This is leading me to the Error code 1349. Could anyone help me rearrange the query?

```
create view QueryView as (Select 
System, Cast(Sum(Duration) as unsigned) AS 'Sum'
From
tbl_Events
    INNER JOIN
(trans_GU, tbl_G, trans_GM) ON (trans_GU.Unit_ID = tbl_Events.Unit_ID
    AND trans_GU.GIB_SN = tbl_G.SN
    AND tbl_G.EQUIPCODE = trans_GM.EQUIPCODE
    AND tbl_G.GEN_MODEL = trans_GM.GEN_MODEL)
WHERE
trans_GM.ProductLine = 'fleet'
GROUP BY System
Order By Sum desc
Limit 10) 
Union 
(Select 'Other' As System, Cast(Sum(a.`Sum`) As Unsigned) As 'Sum' FROM (Select 
'Other' As System,
Sum(Duration) AS 'Sum'
FROM    tbl_Events
    INNER JOIN
(trans_GU, tbl_G, trans_GM) ON (trans_GU.Unit_ID = tbl_Events.Unit_ID
    AND trans_GU.GIB_SN = tbl_G.SN
    AND tbl_G.EQUIPCODE = trans_GM.EQUIPCODE
    AND tbl_G.GEN_MODEL = trans_GM.GEN_MODEL)
WHERE
trans_GM.ProductLine = 'fleet'
GROUP BY System
Order By Sum desc
Limit 10,99999999) As a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct.  MySQL does not support subqueries in `from` clauses.  You can rewrite the second part of the query as without the subquery:

```
(Select 'Other', cast(Sum(Duration) as unisgned) AS "Sum"
 FROM  tbl_Events INNER JOIN
      (trans_GU, tbl_G, trans_GM)
      ON (trans_GU.Unit_ID = tbl_Events.Unit_ID
          AND trans_GU.GIB_SN = tbl_G.SN
          AND tbl_G.EQUIPCODE = trans_GM.EQUIPCODE
          AND tbl_G.GEN_MODEL = trans_GM.GEN_MODEL)
 WHERE trans_GM.ProductLine = 'fleet'
 From tbl_RAM
 GROUP BY System
 Order By Sum desc
 Limit 10,99999999
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried this but I returns me more than one 'Other' row. This is the reason why I make subquery.